# nodejs block html in socket.io messages

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, socket.io, format

When someone sends html code in message it can execute on another client and i want to show only text so for example:

`'<h1> test text </h1>'`  should be `'test text'` without the `<h1>` tag

My code:

Server:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on("send_message", async (data) => {
    // send event to receiver
    let socketId = users[data.receiver];
    io.to(socketId).emit("new_message", data);

  });

})
```

Client

```
socket.on("new_message", (data) => {
    const formattedMsg = { username: data.sender, text: data.message, date: data.date, offerId: data.offerId }
    output(formattedMsg);

})

function output(message) {
    if (message.offerId == offerId) {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = `${message.username} o ${message.date}: ${message.text}`

        chatBox.appendChild(div);
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)